# Monitor Auth Status from Firebase using StreamProvider 4.0.1 in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-provider

I am trying to auto login a user if they haven't expressly signed out from the app. I am using firebase for authentication and provider package from pub to monitor the auth status changes.

I have a service dart file (originally from TheNetNinja tutorials) which exposes a stream and wrapped the `main.dart` file with a stream provider. As I understand that in `provider 4.0.1`, one can no longer use `.value and supply the value` like below:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
// This widget is the root of your application.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamProvider<User>.value(
    value: AuthService().user,
     child: MaterialApp(
     debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
     title: 'Flutter Brewzz',
     home: Wrapper(),
   ),
  );
}
```

}

but to change to something of this sort, using `create instead of value` like below:

```
class FoodMart extends StatelessWidget {
// This widget is the root of your application.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamProvider(
    create: (_) => AuthService().user,
    child: MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      onGenerateRoute: Router.generateRoute,
      home: Landing(),
    ),
  );
}
```

}

I have closed and re-opened the app but still not re-directing to home page. Am I doing this wrong?
Here's the implementation of `AuthService.dart` class:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:food_mart/models/users.dart';
import 'package:food_mart/services/database.dart';

class AuthService {

FirebaseAuth _mAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

Stream<User> get user {
  return _mAuth.onAuthStateChanged.map(_mapUserFromFirebase);
}

User _mapUserFromFirebase(FirebaseUser firebaseUser) {
  return firebaseUser != null ? User(userId: firebaseUser.uid) : null;
}

Future createUser(String email, String pwd, String role) async{
  try {
    AuthResult result = await _mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: pwd);
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = result.user;

    await DatabaseService(userId: firebaseUser.uid).setUserData(email: email, role: role);
    return _mapUserFromFirebase(firebaseUser);
  } catch(e){
    print(e.toString());
    return e;
  }
}

Future loginUser(String email, String pwd) async{
  try {
    AuthResult authResult = await _mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: pwd);
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = authResult.user;
    return _mapUserFromFirebase(firebaseUser);
  } catch(e){
    print(e.toString());
    return null;
  }
}

Future signOut() async {
  try {
    return await _mAuth.signOut();
  } catch(e){
    print(e.toString());
    return null;
  }
}

}
```

The `User` model has been left out for brevity. Any suggestions please? Thanks

Comment: Are you storing the username and password, or a token locally on the local storage?   Is there something I've missed in your code doing this? How do you expect the app to re-authenticate the user?

Comment: The authstatechanged method put in the stream, ideally and practically (before using flutter) works that way ===> express sign in until signed out

Comment: I can't get the stream to read that value in main.dart, maybe because I set it up wrong?

Comment: But if you are closing and re-opening the app, whatever was stored in memory is lost. You need to get a token and store it locally, with SharedPreferences for example. If you need an example of how to generate a token and store it on your app locally, I can write it on an answer.

Comment: That's not how firebase works sir. You have to sign out to be redirected or monitor authentication state to keep home page open, i.e bypass re-authentication.

Comment: Sorry. I'm not sure what you're speaking about. You're saying that you expect to fully close your app and, when you re-open i,t your user will still be logged in without saving any authentication details on non-volatile memory?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but the code above works.

```
  class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

    if(user == null){
      return Landing();
    }else{
      return Index();
    }
  }
}
```

Just like you it didn't change the page for me. Turns out the code was working all along, only I was logging in the user from another page called `LoginWithEmail` which was pushed into the stack on a button event from the `Landing` class. I just did a `Navigator.pop()` on `LoginWithEmail` after logging in to realize that the `Wrapper` class changed into `Index`.

```
//code call inside login button onpressed from LoginWithEmail class
AuthService _authService = AuthService();
_authService.loginUser(email, password).then((value) {
   User user = value;
   if(user!=null){
     Navigator.pop();
   }
}
```